# flask Dynamo CreateTable operation Issue (botocore.exceptions.ClientError)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-dynamodb

Try to create table with three fields in Dynamo db by using using flask-dynamo got error ""

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError
>   botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributesdefined in attribute definitions

Here goes the configuration create table dynamo db

```
@app.route('/create_table')
def create_table():
    app.config['DYNAMO_TABLES'] = [
    {
        'TableName': "user_detail",
        'KeySchema': [
            {'AttributeName': "timestamp", 'KeyType': "HASH"},
            {'AttributeName': "question", 'KeyType': "RANGE"},
        ],
        'AttributeDefinitions': [
            {'AttributeName': "timestamp", 'AttributeType': "S"},
            {'AttributeName': "question", 'AttributeType': "N"},
            {'AttributeName': "user", 'AttributeType': "N"},
        ],
        'ProvisionedThroughput': {
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 40,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 40
        }
    }]
     dynamo = Dynamo(app)
     with app.app_context():
          dynamo.create_all()
     return "Table created"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the following line:

```
{'AttributeName': "user", 'AttributeType': "N"},
```

With DynamoDB (as with most NoSQL databases) you don't need to specify every record attribute field ahead of time. You only need to specify the hash and range fields ahead of time.

Comment: I'm beginner of dynamo db ,how i define more than two attribute

Comment: You don't define those other attributes as part of the table schema, ever. You simply insert records with whatever attributes you want (in addition to the hash and key attributes).